# JavaScript add json to existing object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm struggling with adding JSON to existing objects with Vue.js.
So I have a function that is calculating some variants and it's working well for now, but I would need to change them in order to give correct data to my Laravel backend.

So this is how my array looks like (this array is used to calculate variants)

```
"attributes":[
      {
         "title":{
            "text":"Size",
            "value":"1"
         },
         "values":[
            "Red",
            "Green"
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":{
            "text":"Color",
            "value":"2"
         },
         "values":[
            "X",
            "M"
         ]
      }
   ]
```

And I'm calculating them like this:

```
addVariant: function () {
            const parts = this.form.attributes.map(attribute => attribute.values);
            const combinations = parts.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));
            
            this.form.variants = combinations;
        },
```

And the output looks like:

```
"variants":[
      [
         "Red",
         "X"
      ],
      [
         "Red",
         "M"
      ],
      [
         "Green",
         "X"
      ],
      [
         "Green",
         "M"
      ]
   ]
```

So this is calculated well, but this variants would need to look like this:

```
"variants":[
        {
            "title": "Red/M",
            "slug": "prooooo",
            "options": [
                {
                    "key": "Color",
                    "value": "Red"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Size",
                    "value": "M"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Red/X",
            "slug": "prooooo",
            "options": [
                {
                    "key": "Color",
                    "value": "Red"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Size",
                    "value": "X"
                }
            ]
        }
```

As you see I have a title field that is calculated by options.values, but the real question is how to make that JSON look like the last given JSON.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, the missing values to create the final output are the `key` properties of the `options` arrays, which I see in the first `attributes` array under the `text` property of the `title` object.

The first change that you can do is on the creation of the `parts` variable: instead of returning the `attribute.values` directly, `map` over them to save the `attribute.title.text` as well.

At the same time, we set the keys of the returned object to match the `options` object from the desired output.

```js
const parts = this.form.attributes.map((attribute) =>
  attribute.values.map((value) => {
    // `options` objects have `value` and `key` properties
    return { value, key: attribute.title.text };
  })
);
```

The `combinations` code remains the same.

Then, we loop over the `combinations` and create the new `variants` array

```
let variants = [];

for (const combination of combinations) {
  variants.push({
    // use template strings to create the new title
    title: `${combination[0].value}/${combination[1].value}`,
    slug: "...the value that you want",
    // the "combination" variable already has the structure that you want for "options"
    options: combination
  });
}
```

The final code will look something like this:

```js
addVariant: function () {
  const parts = this.form.attributes.map((attribute) =>
    attribute.values.map((value) => {
      return { value, key: attribute.title.text };
    })
  );

  const combinations = parts.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map((w) => [].concat(v, w))), [])
  );

  let variants = [];

  for (const combination of combinations) {
    variants.push({
      title: `${combination[0].value}/${combination[1].value}`,
      slug: "...the value that you want",
      options: combination,
    });
  }

  this.variants = variants;
}
```

Comment: I believe that that code is the one I need, only thing is that value" is not defined on the instance, it says in console

Comment: Actually value is not part of that function, so it seams that this code don't work as expected :/ It actually says that Object(...) is not a function

Comment: Can you point me to the line that causes the problem? It worked fine when I tested the code

Comment: It's actually after variants variable, I tried to delete foreach function and return variants with combinations const and it works, if foreach is in the code it's not working

Comment: Omg it works now, It was probbly because of this value... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Glad it worked! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped